# Regex for multiple spaces between words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that detects words inside a string. My regex works fine when the class consists of a single word, but not for multiple words.

```
function repl(string){
  return string.replace(/<span class="[a-z\s\-\b \b]*">/ , (n)=>{
  return <Symbol/>
}
}
```

Works:

```
repl('<span class='hi'>') /==> <Symbol/>
```

Does not work:

```
repl('<span class='hi hi'>')
```

Comment: The RegExp you provided should *not* match `<span class='hi'>`, since your pattern explicitly checks for a double quote delimiter for the class string itself, not a single quote as the test case uses.

Comment: Why not use a proper (X)HTML/XML parser instead of trying to chop up markup yourself? There are *so* many edge cases with this type of markup that in almost 100% of cases it doesn't make much sense to try to roll your own parser (see [the canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/269970))

Comment: When the test cases are adjusted to use `"` for delineating the class attribute value string, it seems that the tag is still matched by the pattern you've built. ([Regex101 demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/QHmxUk/1)) What *exactly* does "*does not work*" actually mean? Can you clarify your problem statement a bit more? See also: [ask]

Comment: Several of the items in your current attempt seem out of place. You probably tried to say something like `"[a-z\s-]*"`; what did you hope the space and the multiple `\b`s would do that `\s` doesn't?

Comment: In addition, your code appears to contain multiple syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your expression to: `/<span class=["'][a-z_\-][\w\s\-]*["']>/i`

Make sure your HTML element attributes are double-quoted.

**Note:** Please be aware that the closing `</span>` tag [is mandatory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) and should never be ommited.

```js
const repl = (str) =>
  str.replace(/<span class=["'][a-z_\-][\w\-\s]*["']>/i, () => '<Symbol />');

console.log(repl('<span class="hi">'));
console.log(repl("<span class='hi hi'>"));
console.log(repl('<span class="one two  three   ">'));
```